# How to block all Software Update Notifications in macOS?

Tags: macos, software-update, upgrade, notifications

The *Software Updates* in *System Preferences* are all disabled. In spite of this macOS continues to show Notification Banners in Catalina (and Big Sur) which some users accidentally click to initiate an update. **I want to stop macOS from showing all the Software Update notification banners** to prevent accidental updates. Yet I still want to be able to manually initiate software updates when desired.

Previously the following has been suggested:

1. `softwareupdate --ignore “macOS Big Sur”`, but this is not available any more as a command option and would block only major upgrades not minor or security upgrades AFAIK. (Only available in High Sierra up to Catalina with *Apple Business Manager* enrollment, *Apple School Manager* enrollment or Enrollment in a *user-approved MDM*)
2. Moving `com.apple.SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.plist` from `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` to `/System/Library/LaunchAgentsIgnored`, but in order to make these changes, one must boot from another disk, otherwise `System` is read only. Also the notification will reappear if *Software Updates*  is selected in *System Preferences*. This is cumbersome as it means a lot of steps including additional reboots when updates are desired and manually initiated.

I am currently testing another proposed solution which is to install the [Lulu application firewall](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) and then to block  `/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated`.

Blocking and re-enabling `softwareupdated` for manual updates would be less cumbersome than disabling and re-enabling the system protected LaunchAgent, but I am not quite sure, if it will actually prevent the notifications from appearing. Who can confirm that this works in the long run?

Are there any other options to accomplish this?

*Related questions: [How to block updates to Mac OS X Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367995/how-to-block-updates-to-mac-os-x-catalina) / [Remove macOS Big Sur "Upgrade Now" button in System Preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406545/remove-macos-big-sur-upgrade-now-button-in-system-preferences) / [How can I permanently disable App Store notifications in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409093/how-can-i-permanently-disable-app-store-notifications-in-big-sur)*

Answer (score 5):

I have now tested blocking `softwareupdated` for a few weeks and it works as intended. - This has recently become even more important, since the Monterey update from 12.2.1 to 12.3 has caused serious issues with AMD 5000 and 6000 series graphics cards for many users.

### TL;DR

**The short answer is to install the** [**LuLu Application Firewall**](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) **and** ***block*** **the process** `softwareupdated` **when prompted. Re-enable it temporarily when you want to do manual updates.**

### Detailed Step-by-Step

The obvious first step is to completely disable all updates in *System Preferences*, but surprisingly this alone does not stop the clickable notifications.

##### Download and Install Lulu

[Objective-See: LuLu Application Firewall](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) - Big Sur is recommended for version 2.4. Also available is version 1.2 for older macOS versions.

##### Initially enable all firewall prompts

- *Lulu Preferences > Rules > Uncheck All,* so that you will see all Firewall prompts initially.

##### Trigger a Software Update Request

- System *Preferences > Software Updates > Advanced* change any update setting to trigger a software update request
- Block when asked

  - Creates a new firewall rule

##### Disable Software Updates

- In System *Preferences > Software Updates > Advanced* - make sure that all software update settings are set to disabled
- Wait for the timeout

#### Manually Check for App Updates and/or macOS Updates

- In *Lulu > Rules* search for *softwareupdated* and temporarily allow software updates
- Double click on the rule and change to *Allow*

##### Enable Software Updates Temporarily

- System *Preferences > Software Updates > Advanced* activate the items you wish to update

##### Reenable the Firewall Rule blocking Software Updates

- In *Lulu > Rules* search for *softwareupdated* and block software updates again
- Double click on the rule and change to *Block*

##### Disable Software Updates Again

- System *Preferences > Software Updates > Advanced* deactivate all automatic updates again

Note: this method may still not be idiot proof if a user uses System Preferences directly: I have seen the *Monterey 12.3 Software Update* actually re-appear inside System Preferences after a while in spite of software updates being blocked by the firewall. This may be due to initial caching of the update information.

See also my article: [Block Update Notifications - Guide with Screenshots](https://chriswayg.gitbook.io/opencore-visual-beginners-guide/advanced-topics/block-update-notifications)

Comment: Crazy that switching off "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" appears to have no effect.

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you for writing this answer. I blocked the connection from softwareupdated to apple.com. This caused the Software Update preference pane to say, "Unable to check for updates. The network connection was lost." So far so good. I will watch for any further notifications about updates.